# Is there difference between local and laravel run Javascript code?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I have this code that works good.  I tested at my localhost and my server. I add this code into my Laravel project. but somehow this generateFields doesn't show up. I use excatly same js and css CDN. and I checked the .js file included at html sorce code. Could someone teach me what might be cause please?

Whole code

https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/ec15ytmq/20/

This container doesn't show up.

index.html

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

app.js

```
generateFields: (fieldNumber) => {
      Array(fieldNumber).fill().map((v, i) => {
        const ref = i + 1;
        $('#container').append(
          `<div class="fieldContainer">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <input type="text" class="search" data-ref="${ref}" placeholder="type something" class="form-control" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" />
      <span class="search-clear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" data-ref="${ref}"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group resultUl" data-ref="${ref}"></ul>
    </div>`
        )
      });
    },
```

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors or tried stepping through your code? It sounds like you gave up without even trying to debug it?

Comment: Dear @ADyson Thank you for comment. I'm beginner of JS so I don't know how to debug. In this case Could you teach me how to debug? Can I see something in console of Firefox?  Actually Today this problem solved. I didn't change any but start again Laravel server and delete the js file path and type it again etc. then it fixed. Thank you for comment. I appreciate that.

Comment: Yes you need to use the Developer Tools in your browser to debug. There is the console, also the Network tools (for ajax requests etc) and lastly the JS code debugger where you can step through the code line by line. I can't teach you in a single comment here but if you're using Firefox, then Mozilla produce [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/son/docs/Tools) about the available tools. You can also find other tutorials etc online with a simple search.

Comment: Dear @ADyson Thank you so much for answering me. I see ! those are so amazing! I will study hard!